# How to get Bhattacharyya Distance in Excel (or Matlab, or R)

Tags: r, distributions, excel, histogram, similarities

I have several histograms which I would like to compare to one reference histogram to see which one is the most similar to the reference in terms of the shape of the distribution.

Kologorov-Smirnov gives unhelpful answers as often the largest difference in y-value is not indicative of worst fit. From inspection-by-eye, the shape of some this method says to be the worst fit are actually the most similar in shape, but with the distribution shifted up or down the x-axis.

Chi squared: not sure how I'd implement this as my data are continuous (continuous numerical data on x-axis, frequency of these, binned, on y-axis), so offput by the fact that the number of bins I arbitrarily choose to include has such a large effect, and don't know about degrees of freedom.

I don't need a good P-value, just to know qualitatively which of a variety of histograms are most similar to an initial histogram. None of the histograms follow a normal distribution or an approximation of a normal distribution.

From reading, the Bhattacharyya distance seems like a good way of getting what I am looking for, but I don't know how to get this from my excel histograms and data.

A description of how someone with excel and *very* limited matlab skills might compute bhattacharyya distance, or any other suggestions of how to qualitatively say which of several histograms is most similar in terms of shape to a reference histogram would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78849/measure-for-separability/78855#78855) although the question is different. Probabilistic separability measures in R separability.measures <- function ( Vector.1 , Vector.2 ) { # convert vectors to matrices in case they are not Matrix.1 <- as.matrix (Vector.1) Matrix.2 <- as.matrix (Vector.2) # define means mean.Matrix.1 <- mean ( Matrix.1 ) mean.Matrix.2 <- mean ( Matrix.2 ) # define difference of means mean.difference <- mean.Matrix.1 - mean.Matrix.2 # define covariances for supplied matrices cv.Matrix.1 <- cov ( Matrix.1 )

Comment: Because the full code appears elsewhere and this does not address the request for Excel or Matlab solutions, it really ought to be posted as a comment rather than an answer.  If you were to replace the code by an *explanation* of its construction that would allow for porting to other platforms it would make a fine answer.

Comment: It might be nice to post a couple of these histograms for people to see, if you can.

Comment: [Bhattacharya distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance#Bhattacharyya_coefficient) would suffer from the same issue as K-S - it will indicate a discrepancy when there's just a shift.

Comment: Thank you. I said R would be okay in the question title because I do have access to R, and if no-one knew a way of doing this in the other two formats, I am willing to try to start from scratch with R to get this done. 

The code looks helpful: if someone could tell me similar in matlab or excel, or tell me how I would get my data into R in a format which would work with this code I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Use the fpc package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/fpc.pdf

```
library(fpc)
bhattacharyya.dist(mu1, mu2, covarianceMatrix, covarianceMatrix2)
```

Can use `cov` to help calculate covariance.